# What is a good symbol for day of birth?

Tags: symbols

I am using the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) package and it includes a nice header with symbols for email ([`\Letter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marvosym)) and mobile phone ([`\Mobilefone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marvosym)). I can't however seem to find a good symbol for a birth date. I was thinking of something like [this](http://www.bbshirts.nl/zwitsal-p-75.html) but the closest thing I found in the [comprehensive symbol list](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) was `\Maggie` from the [`simpsons`](http://ctan.org/pkg/simpsons) package.

Can someone suggest a good symbol for a birth date?

Comment: `moderncv` uses symbols from the [`marvosym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) package, but I don't think this package includes a good "birth" symbol. Conventionally, an asterisk "*" is used for date of birth.

Comment: Use your star sign:) and there are plenty of packages that provide them.

Comment: The intro to the 60's TV show "Ben Casey" showed the asterisk as the symbol for birth also. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjq1P5p3fso

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Often, an asterisk (`*`) is used to denote dates of birth. An example is the [German Wikipedia entry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Ervin_Knuth) for Donald E. Knuth.

The corresponding symbol for dates of death is the dagger (`†`), produced by, e.g., `\textdagger`.

Comment: +1 for `\textdagger`, which lead me to this page. ;-)

Answer (score 24):

You can get genealogic symbols as side effect when loading the [`genealogytree`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) package. Currently, the symbols are not available as a font elements but as graphics (which should make not too much differenc to a user). `\gtrsymBorn` is the symbol for day of birth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
Donald Ervin Knuth, \gtrsymBorn~January 10, 1938.

\bigskip
Legend: \gtrSymbolsFullLegend

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any for place of birth too or even citizenship/nationalities?

Comment: @FäridAlijani No, I fear there is no symbol for such things (not in the package and not in common usage as far as I know).

Answer (score 21):

I found this command in the Genealogic Symbols:

`\textborn`

which gives a star (similar to an asterisk, indeed).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mattia. Which package must one load to get that symbol?

Comment: @JohnWickerson The needed package is `textcomp`. Mattia, can you please add this info to your answer? And, BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

I like the `\textborn` symbol, just like [here, in the answer of Franck Pastor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238885/93175). Franck also shows what it eventually looks like, and I think this looks better than the symbol of the `genealogytree` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand{\oldtextdied}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textdied}}
\newcommand{\oldtextborn}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textborn}}

\begin{document}

\textborn\,1984, \textdied\,2005
\oldtextborn\,1984, \oldtextdied\,2005 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `\faBirthdayCake` from the fontawesome package