# kpfonts changes appereance of textcomp symbols

Tags: fonts, kpfonts, textcomp

I'm using the genealogic symbols `\textborn` and `\textdied` from the `textcomp` package together with the `kpfonts`.

Unfortunately `kpfonts` loads `textcomp` with the `[full]` option (unless someone specifies `notextcomp`) but seems to modify the appereance of said symbols.

If you try out the following example with and without `kpfonts` you will observe that the symbols get changed to a much heavier, darker version when loading `kpfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\textborn\,1984, \textdied\,2005

\end{document}
```

I would like to use the original version of these symbols while staying with `kpfonts`. To achieve this I tried saving them using `\let` with no success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\let\oldtextdied\textdied
\let\oldtextborn\textborn
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\textborn\,1984, \textdied\,2005

\oldtextborn\,1984, \oldtextdied\,2005

\end{document}
```

Also loading `kpfonts` with `notextcomp` and `textcomp` on its own doesn't change this behavior.

Any ideas how to preserve the original appereance of these symbols?

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[euro,warn]{textcomp}
\usepackage[notextcomp]{kpfonts}` but it will affect other chars too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full solution that neutralizes the pesky encoding specific commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbornstd}{TS1}{98}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textdiedstd}{TS1}{100}
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textborn}{TS1}
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textdied}{TS1}
\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textbornstd}{\tc@check@symbol2\textbornstd}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textdiedstd}{\tc@check@symbol2\textdiedstd}
\makeatother
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textborn}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textbornstd}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textdied}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textdiedstd}}


\begin{document}

\textborn\,1984, \textdied\,2005

\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image]

This is the output when `\usepackage{kpfonts}` and the added code are commented out

[image]

So you see that the European Modern TS1 glyphs are used in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

A hacky solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand{\oldtextdied}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textdied}}
\newcommand{\oldtextborn}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textborn}}

\begin{document}

\textborn\,1984, \textdied\,2005

\oldtextborn\,1984, \oldtextdied\,2005 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not that the package loads `textcomp`.  That’s no longer needed explicitly, since it’s part of the LaTeX kernel now, but that lets you use these symbols in 8-bit TeX at all.  It’s that `kpfonts` comes with a companion font that covers those symbols, and you don’t like it.

So, you can change the companion font used with the TS1 encoding back to Computer Modern, using `substitutefont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[full]{textcomp} % No longer needed as of 2020
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{TS1}{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\substitutefont{TS1}{\sfdefault}{cmss}

\begin{document}

\textborn~1984, \textdied~2005

\end{document}
```

[image: KP/Computer Modern sample]

As of 2020, you can remove both the `inputenc` and the `textcomp` packages from your preamble.  A current version of LaTeX will load them both by default.

On a minor unrelated note, you probably want these symbols to be separated from the date by a non-breaking space, `~`, rather than `\,`.  This way, TeX will never break a line between the symbol and the date.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
\usepackage[euro,warn]{textcomp}
\usepackage[notextcomp]{kpfonts}
```

worked for the `\textmarried` :) Thanks David Woitkovski.