# \DeclareTextSymbol and \DeclareTextCommandDefault in contrast to standard \newcommand et al

Tags: macros

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238900/63226) answer egreg used the macros `\DeclareTextSymbol`, `\DeclareTextCommandDefault` and `\UndeclareTextCommand` where I had previously (and unsuccessfully) tried a simple `\newcommand` or `\let`.

Could someone please elaborate on the correct use of these commands and the difference to the standard `\newcommand` etc.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some commands are able to choose their action based on the current output encoding.

The simplest example is that of accents. One wants that `\"` behaves differently when the output encoding (which is a correspondence between the available glyphs and their position in the font) is OT1 or T1.

In the first case, `\"u` would compose the output from an accent and a character, with T1 it will directly typeset a precomposed character (this difference is very important when hyphenation is considered).

So, rather than maintaining a list of commands to change the definition of when switching encodings, a command can be defined with `\DeclareTextSymbol` or alike functions.

Let's look at `\textborn`. It is undefined in base LaTeX, but `textcomp` provides a definition of it:

```
% textcomp.sty, line 225
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textborn}{\tc@check@symbol2\textborn}
```

It's not important to know what the replacement text is supposed to do, but this defines `\textborn` as

```
\?-cmd \textborn \?\textborn
```

(three tokens, the last is a single token whose expansion is the above replacement text `\tc@check@symbol2\textborn` and can be accessed at by doing `\csname ?\string\textborn\endcsname`).

Later on, when `ts1enc.def` is loaded, because `textcomp.sty` implicitly calls `\usepackage[TS1]{inputenc}`), LaTeX will find

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textborn}{TS1}{98}
```

that will do a similar trick as before, defining `\textborn` as

```
\TS1-cmd \textborn \TS1\textborn
```

(again three tokens). This is the most important part. How does a command like this work?

At expansion of `\textborn`, if LaTeX is in a place where a character is expected to be typeset, the current output encoding will be checked against TS1. If it is, then just glyph number 98 of the current font will be used; otherwise a group is opened, the encoding switched to TS1, character 98 is typeset and the group is closed.

<sup>Such a command is always robust, meaning that if found in moving arguments it will produce itself instead of expanding when write operations are involved.</sup>

This should explain your perplexity when doing

```
\let\oldtextborn\textborn
```

before loading `kpfonts` and then seeing no difference between the output produced by `\textborn` and `\oldtextborn`. The `kpfonts` package doesn't redefine `\textborn`, but rather associates a new font to the TS1 encoding based on the chosen font family name. So `\oldtextborn` and `\textborn` are still the same.

For defining `\textborn` to use the `cmr` family one has to be careful, because a strategy like

```
\let\oldtextborn\textborn
\renewcommand\textborn{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\oldtextborn}}
```

is not guaranteed to be safe. For instance, if `\textborn` appears in a moving argument, say in a section title or a caption, the `.aux` file will contain

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}{\fontfamily  {cmr}\selectfont  {\fontfamily  {cmr}\selectfont  \textborn }}}{1}}
```

where the command appears to be expanded a few times. In other circumstances this might even lead to infinite loops.

A strategy involving `\UndeclareTextCommand` is definitely safer.